# Spring Security OAuth2 Generic Configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am trying to setup a spring security (v5.8.8) configuration to connect to different OAuth2 authorization servers. I am testing with Azure and Okta. I would prefer to only use Spring Security without the implementation spring oaoth2 starters for each OAuth2 authorization server.

I have a web application that is working with a normal spring security with custom login page. Now I want to switch the security config to OAuth2 version. The properties I am using for OAuth2 are :

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider=okta
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta.issuer-uri=https://cs-docker-test.us.auth0.com/

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-id={client-id}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-name={client-name}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-secret={client-secret}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.provider=okta
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/okta/
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.scope.0=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.scope.1=profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.scope.2=email
```

The security config I am trying to use is :

```
        httpSecurity
        .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> {
            oauth2.userInfoEndpoint(ep -> 
            ep.oidcUserService(customOidcUserService(coreSuiteZkJwtAuthorizationProperties())))
            .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    System.out.println ("In Authentication Success Handler");
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/" + WorkbenchConstants.HOME_PAGE);
                }
            })
            .failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    System.out.println ("In Authentication Failure Handler");
                }
            });
        })
        .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
        );
```

When I hit the URL in the browser, I am redirected to the Okta server and see the login screen. After I successfully login, the redirect URL is called with the code in a query parameter. At this point, I see a loop of redirecting to Okta and subsequent calls back to the redirect URL.

```
"GET /test HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /test/oauth2/authorization/okta HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /test/login/oauth2/code/okta/?code=xxxxxxx&state=yyyyy HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /test/oauth2/authorization/okta HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /test/login/oauth2/code/okta/?code=aaaaaaaa&state=bbbbb HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /test/oauth2/authorization/okta HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

I am trying to find and understand the code in spring security that processes the calls from Okta to the redirect URL. My understanding is some code will process the response, create an Authentication implementation, place in security context, and call the original URL. I do not see any calls authentication success of failure handlers or my OidcUserService implementation. I see the OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter intercept `/test/oauth2/authorization/okta` and calls sendRedirectForAuthorization. It does not process the call back to the redirect URL and just passed processing to next in the filter chain.

Can someone point to the problem with the configuration or how I can debug the processing of the redirect URL?

Thanks.

UPDATE

Following the information provided in first response, I tried to set a break point in DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient and it was never called upon the callback api being called. As I mentioned, it appears no OAuth2 callback handlers pick up the response and the request goes through to the security filter chain and the Web Request Mapping Handlers.

in the browser web developer tools , I see the following:

```
 - //test-server/test
 - //test-server/test/oauth2/authorization/okta
 - //cs-docker-test.../authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20read%20write&state=xxxxx&redirect_uri=/test-server/test/login/oauth2/code/okta/&nonce=xxxxxx 
 - //test-server/test/login/oauth2/code/okta/?code=xxx&state=xxxx
```

Here is the server log output with spring security set to trace

```
HttpSessionRequestCache- Saved request //test-server/test/ to session
DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint- Trying to match using And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], Not [And [Or [Ant [pattern='/login'], Ant [pattern='/favicon.ico']], And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@181c3334, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]]], org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer$$Lambda$978/0x00000008016324b0@d6c85cb]
DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint- Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint@22d34e56
DefaultRedirectStrategy- Redirecting to //test-server/test/oauth2/authorization/okta
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository- Did not store empty SecurityContext
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository- Did not store empty SecurityContext
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter- Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
FilterChainProxy- Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/actuator/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@3fe0e2c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@14bc0396, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3564af03, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@211826f1, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@65c06aba, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@57ee6e7f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4e914dc, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@79584b0e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1997d57a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2943dd2a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1e8af6e0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@60a58ab3, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@467d2e01]] (1/2)
FilterChainProxy- Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@2bd7234f, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3a874482, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@780e1857, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@66569002, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@8dbe67c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5c5280f7, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@32679564, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@5d599304, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@66dfaedd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@730ad75, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7089c521, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@347c320b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@15ef3b87, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1ef114e0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@590a8963, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@2999efc4]] (2/2)
FilterChainProxy- Securing GET /oauth2/authorization/okta
FilterChainProxy- Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/16)
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository- Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession EF63148EB2828BC5F7B07035AB4945E3 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository- Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter- Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
FilterChainProxy- Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking CorsFilter (5/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking LogoutFilter (6/16)
LogoutFilter- Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
FilterChainProxy- Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (7/16)
DefaultRedirectStrategy- Redirecting to https://cs-docker-test.us.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxx&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20read%20write&state=yyyy&redirect_uri=//test-server/test/login/oauth2/code/okta/&nonce=zzz
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository- Did not store empty SecurityContext
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository- Did not store empty SecurityContext
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter- Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
FilterChainProxy- Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/actuator/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@3fe0e2c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@14bc0396, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3564af03, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@211826f1, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@65c06aba, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@57ee6e7f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4e914dc, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@79584b0e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1997d57a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2943dd2a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1e8af6e0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@60a58ab3, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@467d2e01]] (1/2)
FilterChainProxy- Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@2bd7234f, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3a874482, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@780e1857, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@66569002, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@8dbe67c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5c5280f7, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@32679564, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@5d599304, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@66dfaedd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@730ad75, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7089c521, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@347c320b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@15ef3b87, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1ef114e0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@590a8963, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@2999efc4]] (2/2)
FilterChainProxy- Securing GET **/login/oauth2/code/okta/index.zul?**code=aaaa&state=bbbbb
FilterChainProxy- Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/16)
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository- Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession EF63148EB2828BC5F7B07035AB4945E3 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository- Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter- Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
FilterChainProxy- Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking CorsFilter (5/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking LogoutFilter (6/16)
LogoutFilter- Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
FilterChainProxy- Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (7/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter (8/16)
OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter- Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login/oauth2/code/*']
FilterChainProxy- Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (9/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (10/16)
DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter- Did not render default logout page since request did not match [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]]
FilterChainProxy- Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (11/16)
HttpSessionRequestCache- Did not match request /login/oauth2/code/okta/index.zul?code=xxxx&state=yyy to the saved one DefaultSavedRequest [//test-server/test/]
FilterChainProxy- Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (12/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (13/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking SessionManagementFilter (14/16)
AnonymousAuthenticationFilter- Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=192.168.0.15, SessionId=EF63148EB2828BC5F7B07035AB4945E3], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
FilterChainProxy- Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (15/16)
FilterChainProxy- Invoking AuthorizationFilter (16/16)
```

To me, it appears that somehow the incoming url from Okta is being modified by appending /index.zul which is causing the match on the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` to fail. I am not sure who is modifying the incoming URL.

> FilterChainProxy- Securing GET **/login/oauth2/code/okta/index.zul?*

Answer (score 1):

How the authorization code flow works with Spring Security and `oauth2Login`:

1. browser follows `/test/oauth2/authorization/okta`
2. browser is redirected to authorization server `authorization` endpoint (`https://cs-docker-test.us.auth0.com/authorize` in your case
3. after the user is successfully authenticated, the browser is redirected back to OAuth2 client with an authorization-code (`{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/okta/` in your case, as specified in your conf)
4. OAuth2 client (your Spring server) calls the authorization server `token` endpoint (`https://cs-docker-test.us.auth0.com/oauth/token` in your case) to get tokens. This is direct call from the OAuth2 client to the authorization server (without the end-user browser)
5. OAuth2 client responds with another redirection which depends on the authentication final status

The authentication is successful only if the tokens are successfully retrieved by the OAuth2 client. Otherwize, it is considered failed and the browser is redirected to ... somewhere (I'm not sure I see that in your conf). If this somewhere is protected, then a new authorization code flow is initiated, probable reason for your loop (something probably goes wrong when Spring tries to get tokens with the authorization code, but as you do not provide logs from your Spring application with `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`, I can't tell what).

#### P.S.

For "generic" OAuth2 configuration, you might find [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#oidc-starter) useful. It removes the need for most of Java configuration in favor of application properties,including authorities (roles) mapping, CORS configuration, "almost standard" logout, and more. It works with Azure, Okta and any other OIDC Provider (Keycloak, Amazon Cognito, spring-authorization-server, ...).

Comment: How can I debug the call back from Okta? What I an seeing in the FilterChain is the request coming in to Url https://cs-docker-test.us.auth0.com/oauth/token is actually being changed by another request handler someplace https://cs-docker-test.us.auth0.com/oauth/token/index.xx.

I think that OAUTH2 should intercept before it get to the view requests handlers and FilterChain.

Comment: If you're looking for what sends the request from Spring to https://cs-docker-test.us.auth0.com/oauth/token, set a breakpoint in `DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient`.

Comment: updated question with log output

Comment: You do not provide with your full conf. Maybe you disabled sessions, maybe you do not apply `permitAll()` to authorization-code callback, maybe ... who knows? If you had followed the link to "my" starter, you could have found the OAuth2 tutorials hosted in the same repo, [some of which](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#32-oauth2-client-with-just-spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client) even covering OAuth2 clients without "my" starter.